# Discord.js bot Custom presence with image

Tags: discord, discord.js

Currently trying to use setPresence for my bot, and I can get the name but no extra details for the 2nd line and no images.

```
bot.user.setPresence({
    game: {
        name: "Ready to brawl!",
        application_id: 'the id',
        details: "These sharks are ready for a fight.",
        type: 0
    },
    assets: {
        large_image: "large",
        large_text: "Do not jump into that tank...",
        small_image: "small",
        small_text: "c!help"
      },
    status: "dnd"
});
```

So what shows up is:
My bot is on DND, shows "Playing Ready to brawl!", but nothing else. The details part doesn't show up and there's no large or small image.
I've used a custom presence application before so I assumed you needed your own discord application on the developers site, so I made one. I have the name of it the exact same as the "name: '.' " part and I have the id in the application id part. (I'm not sure if it's bad to share the ID so I excluded it.)
Before I tried using large_image and small_image as pure inputs and gave them links, but neither that nor this application one worked.
So if I'm seriously fucking something up here, help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal, you can't use Rich Presence with a bot **actually**. Maybe someday Discord will allowed this.